# OrientDB - How to update list entries in a record

Tags: list, insert-update, orientdb

Node class contains a property 'OutLinks' of type list. How to update list entries of a particular node instance
I am using rest api.
REST URI is http://x.x.x.x.:2480/command/xxx/sql
Post body contains
update Node set OutLinks = List(#12:1,#12:0) where @rid=#11:0
With this command, existing entries get replaced. Is there a way to insert/append/delete list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SQL UPDATE](https://github.com/nuvolabase/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Update) command, like:

```
update #11:0 add OutLinks = #12:0
update #11:0 remove OutLinks = #12:0
```